# How to remove interpunct and number which followed by fullstop by using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I have a begginer in NLP and I have a dataset for NLP task which has strings. I want to clean it by removing interpunct and nuber which followed by fullstop, such as 'George is · working here since 2015.' to 'George is working here since'.

I want to use regular expression and I think comile library works in my problem. The code that I have is

```
def stripPunc(wordList):
    """Strips punctuation from list of words"""
    puncList = ["]","[","·",".",";",":","!","?","/","\\",",","#","@","$","&",")","(","\""]
    for punc in puncList:
        for word in wordList:
            wordList=[word.replace(punc,'') for word in wordList]
    return wordList
```

but returns

```
['G',
 'e',
 'o',
 'r',
 'g',
 'e',
 ' ',
 'i',
 's',
 ' ',
 '',
 ' ',
 '',
 '',
 ' ',
 'w',
 'o',
 'r',
 'k',
 'i',
 'n',
 'g',
 ' ',
 'h',
 'e',
 'r',
 'e',
 ' ',
 's',
 'i',
 'n',
 'c',
 'e',
 ' ',
 '2',
 '0',
 '1',
 '5',
 '']
```

instead of 'George is working here since'.

One more aproach is to use

```
import re

re_word_pattern = re.compile(r'\w+')
re_brackets = re.compile(r'(\[|\])')
re_number_to_zero = re.compile(r'\d+')
re_interpunct_to_zero = re.compile(r'')
text = 'George is · [] working here since 2015.'
text = re_brackets.sub('', text)
text = re_number_to_zero.sub('', text)
```

which gives

```
George is ·  working here since .
```

so in this case how could I remove the interpunct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
def clean_text(text):
    return " ".join(re.sub(r'\s*\d+\.|[^\w\s]|_', '', text).split())
```

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/dyQDJy):

```py
import re
s='George is · working here since 2015.'
print( " ".join(re.sub(r'\s*\d+\.|[^\w\s]|_', '', s).split()) )
# => George is working here since
```

*Details*:

- `re.sub(r'\s*\d+\.|[^\w\s]|_', '', s)` - removes a couple of patterns:

  - `\s*\d+\.` - zero or more whitespaces, one or more digits and a dot
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\w\s]` - any punctuation other than `_`
  - `|_` - or a `_`
- `" ".join(...).split()` shrinks the whitespace in the result.

Comment: @George I see, this is a char belonging to the [modifier letter Unicode category class](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Lm), `\p{Lm}`, this is why it is not removed. You can add it to the `_` char that is also a word char, like `r'\s*\d+\.|[^\w\s]|[_ʼ]'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/hPlQ3l).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I was wondering if there is any way in your code to remove all punctuation except dot and #.

Comment: @George Depends on what you really want. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/N7Qo2j).

Answer (score 0):

In your first code, you are iterating through a list, so if you give it a string it will iterate through each character
so what you can do is :

```
def stripPunc(sentence):
    """Strips punctuation from list of words"""
    puncList = ["]","[","·",".",";",":","!","?","/","\\",",","#","@","$","&",")","(","\""]
    for punc in puncList:
        sentence = sentence.replace(punc,'')
    return sentence
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason your code returns the same sentence as an inpute. Should I import something extra thatI forgot it?

Comment: i forgot the reafectation, should be good now :)

Comment: thank you so much for your help!!! I have one more questions, if I want to remove also the '|' for some reason isn't working if I add it inside of the puncList. Do you know why and how could I remove it?

Comment: i tried addinf it to the puncList and it worked for me, i'm not sure what's the problem

Comment: yeah its working. You have actually one more " in the end of the puncList, this was the problem. Thanks a lot again!!!